# Recuperando projeto deletado no Staged E-git

Tags: eclipse, git, github

Bom noite pessoal! Hoje fui tentar utilizar o plugin E-git para um projeto feito no eclipse, seguindo um tutorial da internet. Nunca tive contato com o plugin antes. E devido a este despreparo removi todos os arquivos do 'Unstaged Changed' achando que apenas iria remove-las do commit final, ou algo assim. Após isso todo meu projeto foi excluído. Há como recuperar?

Answer (score 1):

Git não va te ajudar esta vez: o que não é "commitado" pelo menos uma vez não pode ser recuperado.
Porem, o Eclipse pode te salvar: utiliza o "local history" para recuperar arquivos removidos:

http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-55.htm

Ja recuperei arquivos apagados deste jeito com o local history do IntelliJ idea. Isso me salvou um trabalho de um dia entero.